# Is that JSON invalid?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I work with Opencart and extend functionality. At this case - this is a script for extended color options.

The situation is generalL server php generates json-string JavaScript works with. Example of JSON test string:

```
{
    "110": {
        "black": {
            "hexcolor": "000000",
            "image": "http://ocart.com/image/cache//ajaxcolor/71653fa77e1f98208ff736d6ca0f0909-500x500.jpg",
            "thumb_image": "http://ocart.com/image/cache//ajaxcolor/71653fa77e1f98208ff736d6ca0f0909-228x228.jpg"
        },
        "white": {
            "hexcolor": "000033",
            "image": null,
            "thumb_image": null
        }
    }
}
```

The first element in the hierarchy (110) is html select option value the collection of colors bases on.

The seconds elements ("black" or "white") are descriptions of colors user will see as colored boxes.

The last three fields are used for representation of each selected color.

The problem is: JQuery refuses to work with this JSON:
1. It cannon parse it announcing about

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token on.parseJSON @ jquery-2.1.1.min.js:4(anonymous function) @ ajaxcolor.js:14j @ jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2k.fireWith @ jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2n.extend.ready @ jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2I @ jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2ere

2. Object without parsing looks unusual way:

[image: trying to screen json without parsing]

Here's the example of code

```
    function getProductId() {
    return $("input[name='product_id']").attr('value');
}

function getJson(product_id) {
    console.log("http://ocart.com/index.php?route=ajaxhelper/test&product_id=" + product_id);
    var data = $.getJSON("http://ocart.com/index.php?route=ajaxhelper/test&product_id=" + product_id);
    return data;
    }


$(document).ready(function() {    
    var option_info = (getJson(getProductId()));

    console.log(option_info);
})
```

So please tell me what I do wrong.

Comment: You are not closing the object, you are missing one `}` at the end.

Comment: @Arg0n He's not missing it. It's under the formatted box. I will edit the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$.getJSON()` is an async function. You cannot do

```
var data = $.getJSON("http://ocart.com/index.php?route=ajaxhelper/test&product_id=" + product_id);
return data;
```

Instead, you have to process the results when it comes back:

```
$.getJSON("http://ocart.com/index.php?route=ajaxhelper/test&product_id=" + product_id)
    .then(function(data){
        //Do what you need to do with data
    });
```

Comment: Thank you. That's the solution.

Comment: Wont that cause problems that I use numbers as first element names?

Comment: `"110"` is a string. `110` is a number.